# clarification on difference between totally bounded and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I read that a subset $B \subseteq X$ is totally bounded if:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists a_1,...,a_N \in X \quad \quad s.t.B  \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{N}B_{\epsilon}(a_n)
$$

where $B_{\epsilon}$ means a ball of radius $\epsilon$...

From the same text, it gave two definitions of compactness:

- a set is compact iff any open cover has a finite sub-cover
- a set is compact when given any cover of balls (of possibly unequal radii), there is a finite sub-collection of them that cover the set

I read many threads that differentiate totally bounded from compactness using concepts of completeness (i.e. Cauchy complete).

But given only these definitions, the only difference I see is that totally bounded requires a $\textit{uniform}$ $\epsilon$ radius for all balls, while compactness allows different values of $\epsilon$ for the radii...

How do these definitions apply to for example $[0,1)$ or $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$? Is uniformity of the radii of the ball covers essential to differentiate totally bounded and compactness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset of a metric space is compact iff it is totally bounded and complete. Any subset of a totally bounded set is also totally bounded, but  a subset of a compact set need not be compact. $[0,1)$ and $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ are both totally bounded because they are subsets of the compact set $[0,1]$. However they are not compact because they are not complete. (A subset of a complete metric space is complete if it is closed and it is easy to see that these two sets are not closed in $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thanks, but using the definitions above for a metric space, does this mean that a subset is totally bounded because it can be covered by a finite amount of balls with equal radii ?  on the other hand, do compact subsets have finite covers of possibly unequal radii? --- i mean, is uniformity of the radii essential to the difference between totally bounded and compactness

Comment: Your are right. For  compactness you have to consider balls of varying radii. @LinkL

Comment: okay thanks that clarified things